# Проблема с использованием объектов в подклассе C++

Tags: c++, ооп, наследование

```
class Object
{
public:
    short type;
    Object(short t)
    {
        type = t;
    }
};

class Cube: public Object
{
public:
    type = 1; //Ошибка
};

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

Здравствуйте. В коде выше я создаю подкласс `Cube` , где главный класс - `Object`. В нём я объявляю объект `short type`. В подклассе `Cube` я пытаюсь инициализировать его (задать значение), что я собственно не могу.

**Не бейте, я только учусь, а по этой теме не могу найти ничего.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Инициализировать надо в конструкторе...

```
class Cube: public Object
{
public:
    Cube():Object(1){};
};
```

Т.е. при создании объекта типа `Cube` вызовется конструктор `Object` с переданным ему аргументом 1, который и инициализирует `type`.

Только я бы еще и конструктор `Obect` писал так:

```
Object(short t):type(t){}
```

Comment: Т.е. напрямую изменять объект нельзя, только через конструктор? Извините, перешёл с python-а. Для меня наследование работает так, что все объекты из родительского класса переходят к дочернему, после чего их можно спокойно изменять.

Comment: Всё равно спасибо. Понял, что конструктор переходит к подклассу и через конструктор родительского класса ему задаётся значение.

Comment: Изменять и инициализировать - это разные вещи. При вашем объявлении поля как `public` вы можете менять его откуда угодно... `Cube c; c.type = -5325;`, например...

Comment: да, но мне нужно изменять его именно в подклассе

Comment: Ну делайте это в функциях-членах подкласса.

Comment: Да, через функции работает. Спасибо большое!! Ваш ответ очень мне помог!)