# Как изменять объекты в подклассе напрямую C++

Tags: c++, ооп, наследование

```
#include <iostream>

class Object
{
public:
    short type;
    Object(short t) :type(t) {}
};

class Cube : public Object
{
public:
    Cube() :Object(1) {}; //изменение через конструктор
};

int main()
{
    Cube c = Cube();
    std::cout << c.type;
    return 0;
}
```

В коде выше я объявляю класс `Object` и его подкласс `Cube`. В `Cube` я инициализирую объект `short type` (он объявлен в `Object`) через конструктор. У меня появился вопрос по нахождению способа более простого инициализации и **изменения объектов**. Возможно надо поработать с полями доступа.

Comment: *"на эту тему я почему-то не могу найти информации"* - за это можно и побить, конструкторы и классы рассматриваются с разной степенью паршивости во всех книгах и туториалах по С++ для начинающих

Comment: @AlexGlebe Извините, возможно не правильно выразился. Инициализация вначале. Изменения позже, например изменять координаты x, y для некоторого объекта в качестве реализации движения.

Comment: @user7860670 Извините, не понял претензию. А смысл бить за попытку найти информацию? Если бы я нашёл ответ на свой вопрос, то я бы не писал наверное.

Comment: В том, что этой информации вагон и маленькая тележка, а "не могу найти информации" похоже на бестолковую отмазку в отсутствии попыток что-либо разузнать самостоятельно. Такого типа заявление можно было рассмотреть всерьез если бы оно сопровождалось списком прочитанной литературы / туториалов или каких-других источников.

Comment: @ИльяЧерепанов, а в чем проблема? Вы запустили свою программу и не увидели `1`? (советую добавлять к выводу текст, а в конце **обязательно**  выводить `\n`). Попробуйте теперь после первой печати написать `c.type = 22;` и повторить вывод. Думаю, вопросы сами собой отпадут

Comment: @user7860670 Иду на компромисс. Я изменил вопрос. А теперь можно попросить помощи опытного человека?

Comment: @avp Да, но я спрашиваю про наличие более удобного способа и элегантного способа (да... у меня есть определённые наклонности...)

Comment: @ИльяЧерепанов, насчет более удобного и элегантного способа. Конечно, это зависит от конкретной задачи, но в большинстве случаев, тут сколько людей, столько и мнений будет. Кому-то нравится все упрятывать так, что концов без стакана не найдешь, а другой норовит все внутренности вытащить наружу. Как по мне, так надо всегда помнить о KISS-принципе и не делать ничего лишнего

Comment: метод, объявленный внутри объявления класса подразумевается **inline**, то-есть быстро и прямо. Что ещё надо?

Comment: @Илья Черепанов, насколько я понял, вы путаете  понятия  "класс" и "объект"

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
using std::string;

class Object
{
public:
    short data;
};

class Cube : public Object
{
public:
    Cube() { data = 0; }
    void Func() { data = 1; }
};

int main()
{
    Cube c;
    string input;
    while (input != "end")
    {
        std::cin >> input;
        if(input == "PRINT") std::cout << "C's data is:" << c.data << std::endl;
        if (input == "EDIT") c.Func();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Необходимо изменять объекты с помощью функций подкласса.

Спасибо всем кто помог с вопросом.
P.S. итоговый ответ написал Harry (https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/195342/harry), на первом вопросе ([Проблема с использованием объектов в подклассе C++](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1490799/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b0-%d1%81-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8a%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%b2-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b5-c/1490800?noredirect=1#comment2672152_1490800)), спасибо ему огромное!

Comment: Так объект может быть инициализирован  как угодно,  это простая инициализация в конструкторе .    Ваш вопрос звучал совершенно иначе _ тут нет никакого изменения состояния объектов базового класса в зависимости от объектов производного класса, а есть определенное состояние объекта базового класса для каждого объекта производного.  Так что приведенный вами ответ и вопрос не имеют ничего общего или вы вопрос формулировали не верно. В любом случаи ответ и вопрос не связаны, поэтому минус.

Comment: @ARHovsepyan , Теперь изменил. Вообще этот ответ писал для подведения итогов вопроса, но спасибо за комментарий, возможно теперь поможет не только мне.